# Changing the format that Convert.ToDateTime is produced in

Tags: c#, datetime

I have "02 September 2011" as string and I want to convert it to "02092011".

I am using `Convert.ToDateTime("02 September 2011")` and I am getting "dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00".

How to format so not to include the time?

Comment: ToDateTime produces only *one* format, a DateTime.  What it looks like in the debugger only depends on your machine configuration and is not relevant to your code.  Use its ToString() method next.

Comment: Paul, you have asked 10 questions on this site and **never** accepted an answer. Have you read the FAQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert.ToDateTime("02 September 2011").ToShortDateString()

Answer (score 8):

```
Convert.ToDateTime("02 September 2011").ToString("ddMMyyyy")
```

See more DateTime formatting options [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The most simply scenario is a below:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime("02 September 2011").ToString("d"));
//Example output: 9/2/2011
```

Comment: Also as Hans pointed out please flag and answer. But we will help you anyway, it should be about being a point hoarder.